# loging to linux server appears -bash-4.2

Tags: linux

When I log to linux server by putty. My bash shows: -bash-4.2.

Why my bash is not appearing like [user@localhost]#?

Regards

Comment: Look up $PS1 - an  environment variable to set your prompt!

Comment: This is not a database administration question....